# PHP combining variables error

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to combine several variables:

```
$subject2 = $subject." "."-"." ".$info." "."(".$name.")";
```

This is so that it eventually looks like

$subject - $info ($name)

But this produces an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$subject2' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/hhasbdmx/public_html/gmc_num/form.php on line 17

**Edit**: How would you rewrite this using the sprinf() function?

Comment: `sprintf()` might be what you should be using here

Comment: There might be ";" (semicolon) missing in statement right before $subject2.

Comment: Thanks John. I am not familiar with sprintf(). How would you use it in this scenario?

Comment: You would use sprint() like so: $subject = "some string"; $info = "some string"; $name = "some string"; $subject2 = sprintf('%s - %s (%s)',$subject,$info,$name);